# Transform an array in String. Result => "array...array"

Tags: php

I would like to transform this array in String with implode :

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [technologies_id] => 1 [nom] => PHP [type_technologies_id] => 1 [nom_techno] => Developpement web ) [1] => Array ( [technologies_id] => 3 [nom] => ASP3 [type_technologies_id] => 1 [nom_techno] => Developpement web ) [2] => Array ( [technologies_id] => 5 [nom] => JavaScript [type_technologies_id] => 1 [nom_techno] => Developpement web ) [3] => Array ( [technologies_id] => 6 [nom] => CSS [type_technologies_id] => 1 [nom_techno] => Developpement web ) [4] => Array ( [technologies_id] => 7 [nom] => AJAX [type_technologies_id] => 1 [nom_techno] => Developpement web ) [5] => Array ( [technologies_id] => 17 [nom] => HTML [type_technologies_id] => 1 [nom_techno] => Developpement web ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [technologies_id] => 8 [nom] => Jquery [type_technologies_id] => 2 [nom_techno] => Frameworks web ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [technologies_id] => 22 [nom] => VB 6 [type_technologies_id] => 3 [nom_techno] => Developpement applicatif ) [1] => Array ( [technologies_id] => 23 [nom] => VB.NET [type_technologies_id] => 3 [nom_techno] => Developpement applicatif ) ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [technologies_id] => 28 [nom] => MySQL [type_technologies_id] => 6 [nom_techno] => SGDB(R) ) [1] => Array ( [technologies_id] => 30 [nom] => SQL Server Express [type_technologies_id] => 6 [nom_techno] => SGDB(R) ) [2] => Array ( [technologies_id] => 32 [nom] => SQLite [type_technologies_id] => 6 [nom_techno] => SGDB(R) ) [3] => Array ( [technologies_id] => 34 [nom] => Microsoft Access [type_technologies_id] => 6 [nom_techno] => SGDB(R) ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [technologies_id] => 39 [nom] => SQL [type_technologies_id] => 7 [nom_techno] => Langages d'interrogation de bases de donnees ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [technologies_id] => 46 [nom] => Windows [type_technologies_id] => 9 [nom_techno] => OS ) [1] => Array ( [technologies_id] => 49 [nom] => MAC OS [type_technologies_id] => 9 [nom_techno] => OS ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [technologies_id] => 54 [nom] => Merise [type_technologies_id] => 11 [nom_techno] => Methodologies ) )
```

I tried like this :

```
$string_comp = implode($competences);
```

but I obtained this :

> ArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArray

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: You have a multidimensional array, an array of arrays. Implode only works on 1 level of an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this custom function :)

```
function multi_implode($sep, $array)
{
    $_array = array();

    foreach($array as $val)
    {
        if(is_array($val)) $_array[] = multi_implode($sep, $val);
        else $_array[] = $val;
    }

    return implode($sep, $_array);
}
```

Your implode not working because you are have a multi-array.

Comment: When I call this function, what separator have I to send ? thank you

Comment: @beegees, what ever you want :) Put ' ' (space) for example or ',' (comma). $sep is this separator of the arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of arrays. You must implode each subarray, like this:

```
foreach ($competences as $subArray)
{
    $string_comp .= implode($subArray);
}
```

Comment: @beegees I'm sorry, I forgot `foreach` syntax. I've made proper corrections.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this->

```
$array = array(1,2,3,4);
echo serialize($array);

// Prints

a:4:{i:0;i:1;i:1;i:2;i:2;i:3;i:3;s:3:4;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this:

```
$res = '';
foreach ($arr as $item) {
    $res .= implode('', $item);
}
```

Comment: Or in an one line: $str = implode(array_map('implode', $array))

Answer (score 0):

To get output in a string formate use [serialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) function of php
you can  [unserialize()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) also as its previous state.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you want to access it but personally, I'd just convert it to JSON with [`json_encode($myvar);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). Or have a look at this answer provided on Stackoverflow: [Multidimensional Array PHP Implode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249876/multidimensional-array-php-implode/5249921#5249921).