# How to print a row from 2d array?

Tags: php, arrays, printing, 2d, row

I want to print 1,3,5 rows from 2d array. Can I use some kind of implode or loop?

```
    $array = array(
array(11,12,13,14,15,16),
array(21,22,23,24,25,26),
array(31,32,33,34,35,36),
array(41,42,43,44,45,46),
array(51,52,53,54,55,56),
array(61,62,63,64,65,66)
);
```

I want it to look like this:

"array row 1: 11,12,13,14,15,16"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multidimensional Array PHP Implode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249876/multidimensional-array-php-implode)

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
for($i==;$i<count($array);$i++) {
   if($i%2 !=0) {
      print_r($array[$i]);
   }
}
```

Comment: It might help to actually explain your code, so the OP can learn something from it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `for` loop. for example :

```
for($i==;$i<count($array);$i++) {
   if($i%2 !=0) {
      print_r($array[$i]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to print every odd row of an array :

```
for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++) 
{
   if($i%2!=0) 
   {
      print_r($array[$i]);
   }
}
```