# Best way to implode multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I see some questions but no work to me.

In a for loop i receive an array like that:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "4" } } 

array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "3" [1]=> string(1) "4" } }

array(1) { [0]=> array(7) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "2" [2]=> string(2) "30" [3]=> string(2) "43" [4]=> string(2) "65" [5]=> string(2) "53" [6]=> string(3) "634" } }
```

I need implode that values with "-", my desired output isa string:

```
4

3-4

2-30-43-65-53-634
```

I try some ways, but no work, some ideia for do it simple?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multidimensional Array PHP Implode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249876/multidimensional-array-php-implode)

Comment: @ObsidianAge but the output need to be string, i gona edit

Comment: implode returns a string `echo implode('-',$array);`

Comment: That question is about implode values from a single column, i need implode values from all columns... @ObsidianAge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a two dimensional array and would like to output all elements, you could use a foreach loop and output the implode of each like so:

```
$mainArray = [
    [4],
    [3, 4],
    [2, 30, 43, 65, 53, 634]];

foreach($mainArray as $key => $secArray){
    echo implode('-', $secArray) . '<br/>';
}
```

[PHP Implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Notice the return type of implode is a string.